# Proving a version of Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

**Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem:**

Let $(\alpha_{ij})$ be a square infinite matrix such that for all $x=(\xi_{n}),y=(\eta_{n}) \in \ell ^{2}$ we have that ${\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{ij}\xi_{i}\eta_{j}}$ converges. Then there exists $\alpha>0$ such that 
$$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{ij}\xi_{i}\eta_{j}\right|\leq \alpha\left\|x\right\|_{2}\left\|y\right\|_{2}$$
for all $x=(\xi_{n})\in \ell^{2}$ and all $y=(\eta_{n})\in\ell^{2}$.

**The problem:** I need to show this version of Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem.

**Remark:** I have shown the following facts

> **Fact 1:** Let $E$ be a Banach space and $B:E \times E \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$  (where $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) a bilinear form defined on $E\times E$. If for each $x\in E$ there exists $\mu(x)>0$ such that $|B(x,y)|\leq \mu(x)\left\|y\right\|$ for all $y\in E$, and for each $y\in E$ there exists $\nu (y)>0$ such that $|B(x,y)|\leq \nu(y)\left\|x\right\|$ for all $x\in E$, then there exists $\alpha >0$ such that $|B(x,y)|\leq \alpha \left\|x\right\|\left\|y\right\|$, for all $x,y\in E$.
>
> **Fact 2:** Let $(\zeta_{i})\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence such that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\xi_{i}\zeta_{i}$ converges for all $(\xi_{i})\in\ell^{2}$, then $(\zeta_{i})\in\ell^{2}$.

My idea is to use the two previous facts, for this purpose we define the byilineal form
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
B:\ell^{2}\times\ell^{2} &\rightarrow & \mathbb{C} \\
(x,y)=\left((\xi_{n}),(\eta_{n})\right)&\mapsto & \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{ij}\xi_{i}\eta_{j}.
\end{array}
$$
I want to verify the hypothesis of the **Fact 1**, in that sense I managed to show that the hypothesis

> *for each $x\in E$ there exists $\mu(x)>0$ such that $|B(x,y)|\leq \mu(x)\left\|y\right\|$ for all $y\in E$*

is satisfied. (To demonstrate this verification I use **Fact 2**.)

The **problem** I have is to verify the other hypothesis of **Fact 1**, that is, verify

> *for each $y\in E$ there exists $\nu(y)>0$ such that $|B(x,y)|\leq \nu(y)\left\|x\right\|$ for all $x\in E$*

**One question:** *Is it correct to say that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{ij}\xi_{i}\eta_{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{ij}\xi_{i}\eta_{j} \:\:?. \tag{$\bigstar$}$$*

If the answer is **affirmative** then using an argument similar to how I verified the first hypothesis would prove that the second hypothesis of the **Fact 1** is satisfied. But I am not sure that the answer is affirmative, moreover, I do not know if $(\bigstar)$ is necessary to show the second hypothesis of the **Fact 1**.

As I have no other choice so far, I tried to prove $(\bigstar)$, but my attempts have not been successful. We know that if the serie ${\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{ij}\xi_{i}\eta_{j}}$ converges absolutely, then every rearrangement  converges. I do not know if in this case it is necessary to show that the series converges absolutely to be able to demonstrate $(\bigstar)$, however, I have not been able to show this absolute convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can prove it:
Define
$$
C:l^2 \times l^2 \to \mathbb{C}: ((\xi_n),(\eta_n)) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} \eta_i \xi_j.
$$
Notice that $C(y,x) = B(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in l^2$. You can use Fact 2 again to prove that for each $y \in l^2$ there's a $\nu(y) >0$ such that $\lvert C(y,x) \rvert \leq \nu(x) \|y\|$ for all $y \in l^2$. Then we also have $\lvert B(x,y) \rvert \leq \nu(x) \|y\|$ for all $x,y \in l^2$.

Comment: I assume that for you as for me $x=(\xi_{n})$ and $y=(\eta_{n})$,  then $C(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} \eta_i \xi_j=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \eta_i \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} \xi_j$. In this case by **Fact 2**  you have  $|C(x,y)|\leq \nu(x) \left\|y\right\|$ but not  $|C(y,x)|\leq \nu(x) \left\|y\right\|$, this last conclusion   is only possible if you have $(\bigstar)$, which is the big problem. Could you tell us how to show $|C(y,x)|\leq \nu(x) \left\|y\right\|$?

Comment: Of course, silly of me. You always need the closed graph theorem or something like that to prove this. I'll edit it.

Comment: Nope that's wrong too, the closed graph theorem is already hidden in fact 2. Are you sure that $a_{ij}$ isn't symmetric (i.e. $a_{ij} = a_{ji})?

Comment: There are no assumptions about $(\alpha_{ij})$.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca That can't be right. In the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem being symmetric is always stated as a condition. You could probably find a counterexample of an unbounded bilinear form defined everywhere using axiom choice. Is this some kind of exercise in a course? If so I would ask your instructor about this.